# Which ASP.NET Login system should I use for my project? Membership, SimpleMembership or Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I am creating a sort of intranet system in ASP.NET that requires me to hide/show/disable/enable certain things depending on the logged on user's role. So far I have been using ASP.NET Membership (what I learned in school) however I am running into problems with having to customize things. We need usernames and passwords but we also need to add custom fields like first name, last name, clearance level (which will be used to set the user's role when they are added) and some arbitrary descriptive fields like employee title and office location.

We're using Microsoft Access (OleDB Connection in ASP) for the bulk of our database needs and we have an employee table that stores all the info we need (like names and clearance levels). I wanted to find a way to link records in those tables to the user that was set up through ASP. We need to be able to create, edit and delete users not through the web configuration tool but through the site we're creating (it will be managed by someone not familiar with ASP). Since ASP Membership uses SQL Server, it is becoming complex for me to try and find a way to connect the user tables generated by ASP and the employee tables created for the project.

I have now read online that there are two other versions of this kind of Membership system: SimpleMembership and Identity. Just by habit I'm leaning towards the most recent iteration (Identity), however I am now reading it is harder to query the user tables for appropriate role info and such.

Which would be the best for a system that has 3 specific roles and must disable/hide specific things depending on the role? And which one would be best for allowing me to create my own Add/Edit/Delete pages for users within the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MembershipProvider is depricated and replaced by Asp.Net Identity. Use Identity if this is a new project. Think of migration from MembershipProvider to Identity if it is a brown-field project, but it can take a week of time.

Identity is highly customisable and it is easy to add extra fields on a user and CRUD for users is very easy, especially if you know Entity Framework.

Comment: It is a new project, we began using MembershipProvider but it is still early enough to transfer to Identity. I'm not familiar with Entity Framework but I've done lots of work with MembershipProvider in the past (it's what they taught us in school last year... not sure why they taught us something depricated). Though I am worried about how recent Identity is and its lack of information online compared to MembershipProvider. If Identity can do everything MembershipProvider can, like let me check the logged on user's role and such, then I see no reason not to. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I would say that it's "deprecated", as it will likely be supported indefinitely.  However, asp.net Identity is definitely where all the new development is.

Comment: @AliEgseem yes, Identity can do everything MembershipProvider can and more.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch certainly there is no new developments in MembershipProvider, I call it depricated => no point in using it in the green-field project.